# OWLAPI : Statistics about reasoning task

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

I want to know time taken by a **Reasoner** to get all inferences. How to get that ? Also want to get all statistic information about total tasks performed by the reasoner.

What are the factors affecting the reasoner's performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasoners do not compute 'all' inferences - they compute the inferences required for a particular task.

The factors influencing reasoner performance are many, and how to predict performance over any ontology is an open research question. You can have a look at the results of the ORE competition for comparison of multiple reasoners.

https://www.w3.org/community/owled/ore-2015-workshop/competition/

Comment: is there any way to get statistics (time, no. of tasks performed by reasoner) information for a reasoner ?

Comment: Yes. The results of the ore competition contain that data. The framework used is open source, you can reuse it for your choice of ontology and reasoner.